# Bbcode parser does not work correctly

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I have a problem with BBCodes - this `preg_replace` does not work as intended:

```
$message = preg_replace("/\[color=(\#[0-9A-F]{6}|[a-z]+)\](.*)\[\/color\]/Usi", "<span style=\"color:\\1\">\\2</span>", $message);
```

This works correctly:

```
[color=#ff0000]text text text text text[/color]
[color=#00ffff]texttexttext[/color]
```

**Result:**

[image: Correct result]

But if there are two color tags one after another, it does not work correctly:

```
[color=#ff0000][color=#00ffff]text text text text text[/color] [/color]

[color=#ff0000]text text text[color=#00ffff]text text text text text[/color] [/color]
```

**Result:**

[image: Incorrect resul]

Comment: How about [`preg_replace(['~\[color=(#[0-9A-F]+)\]~i', '~\[/color\]~i'], ['<span style="color: $1">', '</span>'], $str);`](https://eval.in/842053)

Comment: Have you looked at the existing BBCode functions in PHP? http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bbcode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also just do it via 2 replacements.  One for the opening, one for the closing tag.

The nesting of those color tags won't matter then.

```php
$message = preg_replace('%\[color=(\#[0-9A-F]{6}|[a-z]+)\]%i', '<span style="color:$1">', $message);

$message = preg_replace('%\[/color\]%i', '</span>', $message);
```

Or in 1 statement:

```
$message = preg_replace(
[   '%\[color=(\#[0-9A-F]{6}|[a-z]+)\]%i',
    '%\[/color\]%i'
],
[   '<span style="color:$1">',
    '</span>'
], $message);
```

As pointed out by [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/), not considering the nesting could give bad results.

So here's another method that uses a while loop and a recursive regex:

```
$pattern = '%\[color=(\#[0-9A-F]{6}|[a-z]+)\].*?(((?R)|.)*?)\[\/color\]%i';   
$replacement = '<span style="color:$1">$2</span>';

do {
    $message = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $message, -1, $count);
} while ($count);
```

Comment: It's a bad idea, because if the user enters badly formatted bbcode like:`[color=#BBCC99]text[/color][/color][/color]` all closing `[/color]` tags are replaced with closing `</span>` tags, resulting in a badly formatted html. The expected behavior is that unbalanced and badly formatted bbcode tags aren't replaced (then the user can see them and edit).

Comment: To solve the problem, you can use a pattern that describes only innermost balanced bbcode tags, in a `do...while` loop and using the `count` parameter of `preg_replace` to stop the loop.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You're right. Users could make a mess of such tags. So I've added a solution that considers the nesting to the answer.

Comment: Well done, but it's more simple to describe the innermost bbcode tags than writing a recursive pattern to get the outermost.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in the string `[color=#ff0000][color=#00ffff]text text text text text[/color] [/color]` your regular expression matches the first openning with the first closing tags. One way to avoid this is to slightly modify your regexp, for example:

```
/\[color=(\#[0-9A-F]{6}|[a-z]+)\]([^[]*)\[\/color\]/
```

Then it will only match the most nested tags. You need to do this in a loop, while your string contains bbcodes.

Comment: Your idea is IMO the good one.*(to match the most nested tags, and to use a loop)*. However it's a pity to only show the pattern and not the full php code with the loop you are speaking about. As an aside, using `[^[]` is too restrictive since it forbids also tags other than color tags. But your idea with the original pattern works. If you want a greedy pattern that allows other tags you can replace `[^[]*` with `[^[]*(?:\[(?!/?color\b)[^[]*)*`. Your pattern has also many backslashes. To avoid them change the delimiter to `~` and remove backslashes before `#`, `/` and `]`. Add the i modifier.